# Creating a 'Categorical' Variable for Subsets in a For Loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I want to put an operation in a for loop such that the operation is applied to each subset, individually.

The goal is to create a for loop that generates a subset for the variable "State", then assign quantile values (1:4 or 0-25%, 25%-50%, 50%-75%, 75%-100%) for each entry within each subset. It is a little hard to explain so here is an example. My data looks something like this:

---

```
data <- data.frame(data)
```

---

```
State     Summer_Temperature
CA                        72
NY                        84
TX                        91
NY                        70
NY                        74
CA                        70
TX                        95
CA                        71
NY                        99
CA                        67
NY                        86
CA                        70
TX                        101
TX                        110
NY                        60
.                         .
.                         .
.                         .
.                         .
```

---

I have the initial for loop as:

```
for (i in data$State) {
    state.US <- paste("state", i, sep = "_")
    assign(state.US, data[data$State == i,])
}
```

This generates data frames for "state_CA", "state_NY", and "state_TX".
Now I want to create a new variable called "Quantile" for each of these subsets and assign a 1, 2, 3, or 4 to each observation, based on the distribution of temperature for a given state.

(Note: I need quantiles for each subset, rather than the entire dataset altogether.)

---

I know I can do this manually for each state with the code:

```
state_CA$Quantile <- cut(state_CA$Summer_Temperature, breaks = quantile(state_CA$Summer_Temperature), labels = 1:4, include.lowest = TRUE)
```

But I am confident there is a more efficient way than repeating that for all 50 states, and perhaps I can add more operations in the loop once I find a way to do this.

---

This is roughly what the outcome should look like:

```
State     Summer_Temperature           Quantile
CA                        72                  4
CA                        70                  2
CA                        67                  1
CA                        71                  3
CA                        70                  2
NY                        99                  4
NY                        86                  3
NY                        84                  3
NY                        70                  2
NY                        74                  2
NY                        60                  1
TX                        91                  1
TX                        95                  2
TX                        101                 3
TX                        110                 4
.                         .
.                         .
.                         .
.                         .
```

---

This question has been haunting me for a couple months now (various projects from school and work) and I am just about done typing repetitive code when I know theres a better way.

My PhD R-Programming professor was unable to offer help, so if anyone can clarify this for me, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Edit: This is my first time on this side of Stack Overflow, so any tips/criticisms are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to split the datasets into different dataframes and also to use `for` loop, you can do the calculation by group. Using `dplyr` that would be

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(State) %>%
  mutate(Quantile = cut(Summer_Temperature, breaks = quantile(Summer_Temperature), 
                    labels = 1:4, include.lowest = TRUE))
```

Or in base R with `ave`

```
data$Quantile <- with(data, ave(Summer_Temperature, State, FUN = function(x) 
           cut(x, breaks = quantile(x), labels = 1:4, include.lowest = TRUE)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have a follow up question for you, what would I need to change if I wanted a value of 1 (in the Quantile column) to represent 0-5%?

Comment: @jrolfe you can assign custom probabilities in `quantile`, `quantile(Summer_Temperature, c(0, 0.05, 0.5, 0.75, 1))`

Comment: This does not assign values 1:4, rather it provides ranges like:      (1.28e+04, 2.24e+04), or [60, 5.57e+03), and even NA values

Comment: @jrolfe You need add `labels` as well. `data %>%
  group_by(State) %>%
  mutate(Quantile = cut(Summer_Temperature, breaks = quantile(Summer_Temperature, c(0, 0.05, 0.5, 0.75, 1)), 
                        labels = 1:4, include.lowest = TRUE))`